# How to throw an exception from a CodeIgniter library

Tags: php, codeigniter, exception

I've made a CodeIgniter library that depends on a certain method existing.  This method used to be "hidden" (it was not documented, but seemed to work).  Eventually CodeIgniter made it `protected`, so I can't call it from a library.  In the dev version of CodeIgniter on GitHub, there is a new public method that I can use.

In my library, I use `is_callable` to detect which method to use, the old method or the new one.  Problem is, in the current stable version of CodeIgniter, neither exist.  Because of this, the library will fail.  Is there a way I can gracefully error out, or throw an exception from within my constructor?  Currently, if neither method is available, the script will just crash when it tries to call the method.

I don't know what the convention is for a CodeIgniter library not being able to load correctly because a method is missing.

**EDIT**: Here is the line I am asking about:

```
$this->func = is_callable(array($this->db, '_compile_select')) ? '_compile_select' : 'get_compiled_select';
```

If neither of these exist (`_compile_select` or `get_compiled_select`), then it will error out when the library tries to call `$this->func`.  I don't know the convention , can I call `show_error` from a library?  What's the correct way to throw an error from a library's constructor?

Comment: I assume a `try-catch` isn't feasible in this case?

Comment: @Matt:  I don't know if you can throw Exceptions from a library's constructor.  Especially, if you are auto-loading the library.  I don't know what the convention is for a CodeIgniter library not being able to load correctly because a method is missing.

Comment: What's the actual code you're using? And of course, what do you want to happen? Throwing an exception is nothing like "gracefully error out", it will stop the script completely. Did you mean to do something else in a `catch` block or something? Details?

Comment: @WesleyMurch: I've added the code to the question.  I was just wondering if there was a way for my library to say "You can't use this library, you're missing a function", instead of it crashing when it tries to use a non-existent function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the goal is just a pretty error message instead of a fatal error, it's pretty simple really:

```
$this->func = is_callable(array($this->db, '_compile_select')) ? '_compile_select' : 'get_compiled_select';

if ( ! is_callable(array($this, $this->func)))
{
    show_error("You can't use this library, you're missing a function");
}
```

Basically, just don't assume `get_compiled_select` is callable in your conditional - check first.

> can I call show_error from a library?

Yes, this is one of the functions defined in `core/Common.php`, you can use it anywhere in your CI app.

Of course, technically this is not `throw`ing an exception, but it's the convention for Codeigniter. This can be problematic if you want to `catch` errors and try something else:

```
try {
    $this->load->library('might_not_exist', 'alias');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->load->library('definitely_exists', 'alias');
}
```

The above won't work, as `show_error()` will get called by the loader and exit the program before your catch block is executed.

Comment: I wasn't sure if calling `show_error` from a library was convention or not.

Comment: Everything in `Common.php` is globally available. Codeigniter doesn't really have strong conventions, you kinda just make up your own.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that when looking at other people's code :P

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but see this URL i think it is very help full to you.

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/67096/

see also

http://phpcodeignitor.blogspot.in/2011/07/php-exception.html

or try this

MY_Exceptions.php and put it in /applications/libraries/

```
 <?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions{

    function MY_Exceptions(){
        parent::CI_Exceptions();

    }

    function show_404($page = '')
    {
    echo 'test';
    }

    function show_error($heading, $message, $template = 'error_general')
    {
echo 'test';    
}

    function show_php_error($severity, $message, $filepath, $line)
    {
         echo 'test';
         }
}
?>
```

functions in MY_Exceptions do not seem to be overridden at all. functions in Exceptions are the one which are run